# Taylor's approximation

Tags: taylor-expansion

Our lecturer once showed us that it is possible to approximate the value of 'e' with Taylor's approximation of order - whatever, lets say 3. How would. The result was something like this:

$$ 2.700001234<e<2.7290001234$$

He showed us the approximation between two inequalities with a a certain degree of error.
I know how to do the Taylor's polynomial of a function but not the error approximation thing. Can someone show me in a better example?

Answer (score 3):

You should learn about the error term for the Taylor polynomial, see for example [Wikipedia's article about Taylor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem). Using the Lagrange form for the Taylor polynomial of degree three of $e^x$ (around $0$), we find e.g.
$$\tag1e^x= 1+x+\frac12x^2+\frac16x^3+R(x)$$
with $$\tag2R(x)=\frac{e^\xi}{24}x^4 $$
for some $\xi$ between $0$ and $x$.
To compute $e$, we might try $x=1$, so that $e^\xi$ is a number between $e^0=1$ and $e^1<3$ (I assume this simple bound is already known). This makes $\frac1{24}<R(x)<\frac18$, i.e. we find an interval of length $\frac1{12}$ containing $e$. Explicitly, $$2.708\bar 3=2\frac{17}{24}<e<2\frac{19}{24}=2.719\bar 6.$$

---

A nice trick is to estimate $\sqrt e$ and then square, i.e. plug $x=\frac12$ into $(1)$ and $(2)$. This gives us
$$\sqrt e=\frac{79}{48}+R(x)$$ 
and (using the very weak estimate $\sqrt e<2$ for $f^{(k+1)}(\xi)$)
$$\frac1{384}<R(x)<\frac1{192}$$
and from this 
$$ 2.7182344\ldots<e<2.7277\ldots$$
(i.e. we have confined $e$ to an interval of length $<\frac1{100}$, as opposed to $\frac1{12}$ in our first attempt).
Exploiting this trick further,  you could get moderately good approximations for $e$ already from the second degree Taylor polynomial!

Comment: Very nice answer ! Thanks for the trick.

Comment: He showed us exactly like you did in the top part. But I don't understand why R(x) is between $ \frac {1} {24} and \frac 1 8 $ where did those figure come from?

Answer (score 0):

For a fixed $a$, if $f$ is $(n+1)$-times differentiable on $(a,x)$ and $f^{(n)}$ exists and is continuous on $[a,x]$, then  $$
  f(x) = \underbrace{\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!}(x-a)^k}_{:=T_n(x)}+ \underbrace{\frac{f^{(n+1)}(\xi)}{(n+1)!}(x-a)^{n+1}}_{:=R_n(x)} \text{ for some $\xi \in (a,x)$.}
$$
$R_n$ is called the remainder, and this particular formula for it is called the *lagrange* form the remainder. If you know some *bound* for $f^{(n+1)}$ on $(a,x)$, i.e. if you know some $M_x$ such that $|f^{(n+1)}(\xi)| \leq M_x$ for $\xi \in (a,x)$, then you can bound the maximum approximation error with $$
  |T_n(x) - f(x)| \leq |R_n(x)| \leq \frac{M_x}{(n+1)!}(x - a)^{n+1} \text{.}
$$